# Insert external PDF file in Lyx

Tags: lyx, pdf

I am writing a document in Lyx and I want to insert a PDF that is 1 and a half pages long. Before inserting the PDF I have written some text and after inserting it, I have written some more.

However, when I preview the document, the PDF isn't inserted right after the text I have written; it leaves half a blank page, then it starts in a new page. The same happens at the end: it leaves half a blank page, then in the new page the text that comes after the PDF continues.

Is there a way to "fully join" the PDF to the file?

**Summary of the structure**:

Half a page of text + half a blank page

1 page of the PDF

Last half page of the PDF + half a blank page

More text

**What I want**

Half a page of text + 1st half page of the PDF

1 Page of PDF

More text

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please edit your question and at least copy your code which includes the pdf? It should be complete enough, i.e. so we can copy and compile it without further actions. Thanks.

Comment: Just insert the pdf twice  as images without a float,  and in the options of the image, type  `page=1` or `page=2` and set also the size and clipping options as  needed.  If the image have not enough space in the current page, this produces a big gap in the text. To avoid this, consider to do the same but using the images inside a figure float, and play with the float options to control the float final position.